# How can I change this light fixture in my closet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I wanted to change the light fixture in my front closet.  Simple enough task.  I've done this sort of thing hundreds of times.

I turned off the circuit breaker.  I took the old fixture off.  However, I found that the wires were whole with only a small piece of the plastic/rubber covering peeled off from the center from each color.  One wire was white and the other yellow. There are no ends to you would typically find.  I thought it was odd but just went with it.  I wrapped the white wire from the new fixture to the white wire in the ceiling and the black wire from the fixture to the yellow in the ceiling.  Long story - short...When I turned on the electricity the circuit blew. Needless to say what i thought would work, didn't.

I hope all that makes sense. I have not idea how to resolve this, considering it should have been easy.[image: wiring in ceiling. i taped the exposed part][image: this is the old fixture][image: the new fixture is on the right]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the old fixture worked, Then you should be good if all is connected properly. When you say you "wrapped" the new wires onto the wire in the ceiling, I take it you mean just that, and perhaps taped them up (given the first picture) - I'm guessing they came untaped and shorted out when you put the fixture in place.

Cut and strip the wires in the ceiling, and use a correctly sized wirenut or other suitable wiring connector to connect them to the fixture wires.

Comment: What happened is the wires were stripped midway and wrapped around the fixture screws on the original fixture -- so yeah, he'll need to cut the wires and use wirenuts.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I understand what was done on the original fixture. It actually works fine for screw connections (though it's not generally accepted), but a cut, probably a restrip, and a wirenut is required to make it work for pigtails, which the new fixture has.